# Lightspark can't be installed

Tags: raspbian

I try to configure my new Raspberry Pi to play flash (AVM2) (with [deezer.com](http://deezer.com) for example). I'm really new on *NIX systems so I tried several things:

First I installed gnash. Then I tried to install lightspark (for AVM2). However, it failed with an error and the flash didn't work.

[This document](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lightspark) seemed to help but when I run cmake it emits several errors:

```
make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCOMPILE_PLUGIN=1
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..

-- Found gnash path: /usr/bin/gnash
-- The ASM-NASM compiler identification is unknown

-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/nasm

-- LLVM llvm-config found at: /usr/bin/llvm-config

-- LLVM version: 3.0

-- HAVE_SUPPORT_TARGETSELECT_H: 1

-- HAVE_IRBUILDER_H:

-- HAVE_DATALAYOUT_H:

-- LLVM CXX flags: -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.0/include -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -fPIC -Woverloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual

-- LLVM LD flags: -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.0/lib -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm

-- LLVM core libs: -lLLVMLinker-lLLVMArchive-lLLVMBitWriter-lLLVMBitReader- lLLVMInstrumentation-lLLVMipo-lLLVMScalarOpts-lLLVMInstCombine-lLLVMTransformUtils-lLLVMipa-lLLVMAnalysis-lLLVMTarget-lLLVMMC-lLLVMCore-lLLVMSupport-L/usr/lib/llvm-3.0/lib

-- LLVM JIT libs: -lLLVMARMDisassembler-lLLVMARMAsmParser-lLLVMARMCodeGen-lLLVMSelectionDAG-lLLVMAsmPrinter-lLLVMMCParser-lLLVMARMDesc-lLLVMARMAsmPrinter-lLLVMARMInfo-lLLVMJIT-lLLVMExecutionEngine-lLLVMCodeGen-lLLVMScalarOpts-lLLVMInstCombine-lLLVMTransformUtils-lLLVMipa-lLLVMAnalysis-lLLVMTarget-lLLVMMC-lLLVMCore-lLLVMSupport-L/usr/lib/llvm-3.0/lib

-- LLVM JIT objs:

-- Found LLVM: /usr/lib/llvm-3.0/include

-- checking for module 'liblzma'

--package 'liblzma' not found CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message): A
required package was not found Call Stack (most recent call first):

/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333

(_pkg_check_modules_internal) CMakeLists.txt:249 (pkg_check_modules)

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:395
(MESSAGE): Please install the Boost libraries AND development

packages Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:257

(find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Liblzma is comes with [XZ Utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/) which is installed. Boost is also installed.

So I don't understand why lightspark can't be installed.

Could someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left my other answer here for the information; it is actually the direct answer, BUT it seems to me you do not have to build lightspark at all.  It is already available precompiled for raspbian (to understand what that means, read my other answer):

```
> apt-cache search lightspark

browser-plugin-lightspark - High-performance SWF player - Mozilla Plugin (experimental)
lightspark - High-performance SWF player (experimental)
lightspark-common - High-performance SWF player - common data
lightspark-dbg - High-performance SWF player (experimental) - Debug symbols
```

Probably a simple `apt-get install browser-plugin-lightspark` will get you what you want.

Comment: I've installed the browser-plugin-lightspark and lightspark. Unfortunately it crashed on deezer.com but this is a other problem. Thanks for your help !

Comment: BTW if you just want a working flash for mozilla, installing the adobe one from their site into firefox is very easy. I have not tried it on minora or the pi, but if you leave another note here I will, and explain that how to do that.

Comment: Adobe published a ARM version of flash ?

Comment: @Wuip : oh heck I guess not...well never mind that then.  Closed source sucks!

Answer (score 1):

Library packages on linux are pre-built binaries for use by other pre-built packages.  "Build/building/built" and "compile/compiling/compiled" are synonymous in this context.  A *binary* (synonym: *executable*, or "binary executable") is compiled from *source code* but it is not the same thing as the source code and *the source code is **not included** in the binary*.

This is also how other popular desktop OS's (windows, mac) work.  The software is compiled from source code by somebody somewhere and they package it, then you install the *binary executable* package.

Sometimes, however, a piece of software has not been pre-built for use on a particular system (eg, raspbian).  In this case *you* must build the software from the source code, which is what you are trying to do with lightspark. In order to do this, you need some source code "glue" for any libraries that this software makes use of (FYI: not all the source code, just a few small bits, called the *header files* or "includes" used as a plural noun, meaning, "things you include"). That glue is not included in the basic library package, because it is not *normally* needed. It is only needed for compiling code.

So, even though you may have the lzma library installed, you may not have the glue code required to build things with it.  Most likely, that is what the makefile is looking for.  For raspbian, **that glue will be in a `-dev` package.**  The dev package does not replace the library.  It just installs a few extra bits that, again, are not normally needed.

Look:

```
> apt-cache search lzma | grep dev
```

The `apt-cache search` command searches for software available in the raspbian repository; the results are then *filtered* through the `grep dev` command to weed out hits that do not contain the word 'dev'.

```
libarchive-dev - Multi-format archive and compression library (development files)
liblz-dev - data compressor based on the LZMA algorithm (development)
liblzma-dev - XZ-format compression library - development files
lzma-dev - Compression and decompression in the LZMA format - development files
```

So, you could try installing the `liblzma-dev` and `lzma-dev` packages.

Comment: Thanks for you help. If I understand the good way, cmake does not find liblzma beacause their is no liblzma but liblzma-dev ? How could I tell cmake to take liblzma-dev instead ?

Comment: @GuillaumeWuip It's not "instead"; they are two parts of the same thing.  Usually you don't need the dev part.  I've re-written to explain that more clearly.

Comment: Ok, I've understand the system. Your explanation is very useful.Thank you very much !